# My code is showing an error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

my pagination code takes value of page number from a html file and shows the particular page with pagination logic from sql database table.
I have given the code here followed by the error showed.Please help
.thanks in advance!!

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"                         import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"      bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr bgcolor="#66FF99">
  <td>Sr.</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Cost</td>

</tr>




<%


int p= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("textfield"));
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tiop","root","root");
Statement stat=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery("select * From (select * , Row_Number() over   (order by Sr) as RowNum From cre )T where T.RowNum between ((p-1)*5)+1
and (p*5)");

while(rs.next())
{



%>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#99CC33"><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
  <td bgcolor="#669966"><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FF3333"><%=rs.getInt(3)%></td>

</tr>

<%
}

%>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error shown:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /pa.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
26: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
27: Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tiop","root","root");
28: Statement stat=con.createStatement();
29: ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery("select * From (select * , Row_Number() over (order by Sr) as RowNum From cre )T where T.RowNum between ((p-1)*5)+1
30: and (p*5)");
31: 
32: while(rs.next())


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.9 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
```

Comment: Just to remove the obvious: Have you tried to put line 30 in line 29? (i,e, don't end the line where you have, but to put the whole query in the same line)

Comment: @Barranka i tried but i dont know why i am unable to put line 29 in line 30 in notepad

Comment: @Barranka i included the query in the same line but it still shows the same error

Comment: try with a simpler query (for example: `select * from cre limit 10` just to test if your code works.

Comment: Also, instead of using something like `Row_Number()` (which does not exist in MySQL), you can use MySQL's `limit` to paginate your results: take a look to [the reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), specifically, how to use `limit [offset], [rowcount]`

Comment: @Barranka thanks a lot . i will look into it right away.

Comment: @Barranka is it fine if i use the variable p in my sql query directly?( just like i have in the provided code)

Comment: I think you can write your query like this: `select * from cre order by Sr limit (p-1) * 5, 5`

Comment: @Barranka no it still does not work after using your query

Answer (score 0):

*proof of no-errors*
[image: proof of no-errors]

**Solution:** copy and paste following: *@Barranka was right too*

```
String query = "select * From (select * , Row_Number() over (order by Sr) as RowNum From cre )T where T.RowNum between ((p-1)*5)+1 and (p*5)";
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
```

If you're unable to put the full `select-query` on one line. Do following:

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * From (select * , Row_Number() over (order by Sr) as RowNum From cre )T where T.RowNum between ((p-1)*5)+1" + 
"add (p*5)");
```

**Where was the problem?**

> Suggested by StackTrace "*String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote*"

On the `XXX` marker in the following line. A linebreak was causing this issue. `and (p*5)"` was on next line without concatenating.

```
"select * From (select * , Row_Number() over (order by Sr) as RowNum From cre )T where T.RowNum between ((p-1)*5)+1
XXX and (p*5)"
```

**For the sake of simplicity:** store your query in a `String`, concatenate multiple queries, simplify long queries and use them in query execution. Also, helps in reusing that query.

Comment: thanks a lot but i have tried this and it still shows the error

Comment: Show me a proof in a pic. Or the error might be different now.